# How can I disable the mouseover "light-up" effect on a listview or listbox?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, listbox, visualstatemanager

I'm working with Windows 8 app. By default, when you have a listview or listbox, the items will 'light-up' as you hover over then with a mouse.

See an example below: the image on the right is lit up:

[image]

How can I disable that effect? I'm guessing it's something with `VisualStateManager`, but I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

So if we go look at [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709920.Aspx) for the style template of `ListBox` you'll see a `<VisualState x:Name="Focused">` with animation changing the color of `LayoutRoot` to `Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxFocusBackgroundThemeBrush}"`

Giving you some options. You could just get rid of that `VisualState` in the template by just turning this;

```
<VisualState x:Name="Focused">
     <Storyboard>
           <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxFocusBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
           </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

into this;

```
<VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
```

Or you could override that `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxFocusBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />` Brush with say `Transparent` or `#00FFFFFF`

at least that's just a couple ways of doing it, there's several ways I'm sure but you get the idea. Cheers, and welcome to SO.